# Adding variables in string JS

Tags: javascript, html, string, string-formatting

I am using a string to store some HTML. However, the string needs to have some variables. The method I am using to input this variables is encountering  a problem. There are quotes in my HTML. Therefore the string is cutting short where I don't want it to.

```
base="<h2>"+data[i]+"</h2><br><button onclick='vote('"+data[i]+'"); return false'>Vote for ME!</button>"
```

However, I am getting this error.

'vote(' Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Even if I remove the 2 single quotes in the brackets, I am getting an error.

'vote(Iron Man); return false': Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. NOTE: Iron Man is the value of data[i].

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well the quotes are the same So you have an opening one and than the next "opening one inside" is closing it.

Comment: You're switching from double quotes to single quotes after `+data[i]+`.

Comment: It’s recommended to use string templates to avoid this kind of confusion: base=`<h2>${title[i]}</h2>`

Comment: `<button onclick='vote('Iron Man'); return false'>` doesn't work anyway. Why not just use DOM elements to which you can attach listeners functions, instead of html strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a `'` and a `"` flipped around.

```js
base="<h2>"+data[i]+"</h2><br><button onclick='vote('"+data[i]+'"); return false'>Vote for ME!</button>"

                                                               ^^---- flip these two
```

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) can make complicated string concatenations much more readable and less error-prone as it would eliminate the need for most of the `"` double quotes in your code sample:

```js
base = `<h2>${data[i]}</h2><br><button onclick="vote('${data[i]}'); return false">Vote for ME!</button>`
```